# Visual Editor: Paragraph styles appear to one admin but not to others

Tags: editor, css

The first admin of my site has a full Visual Editor with style sheets.
I create new users who are admins (their profile page has same settings with original admin) but they cannot set the style of paragrpaphs (no drop-down list with styles). 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Go to Visual Editor and press ALT+SHIFT+Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all Check If you disabled the visual editor from your profile page.

[See the Screen Shot]
[image: Here is the ScreenShot of Edit Profile Page]

You ned to **uncheck** the box - Visual Editor, the option is located in User's Edit Profile Page.

## UPDATE - 1

2 - You might have been disabled the Kitchen Sink, To enable it Click on small button available in visual editor (Right most button) icon or Press - ***ALT+SHIFT+Z***
[image: enable kitchen Sink]

3 - Or try switching back to default Wordpress theme (TwentyTen or Twenty Eleven) and check if problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this is unchecked for all admins.

Comment: Which Wordpress Version you're using ?

Comment: See the updated answer : You might have been disabled the kitchen Sink Menu in Visual Editor.